# Achieve performance for PostgreSQL on remote database server setup

Tags: python, postgresql, database-performance, postgresql-9.5, odoo-12

I'm Running Odoo 12 Server with PostgreSQL 9.5 running in remote Database server setup. But it is very sluggish. How can I improve the speed of the server while connecting to remote PostgreSQL database.

Comment: do you know the root cause of the performance problems? Slow server hardware, slow network, bad query plans, or something else? And something else, version 9.5 is almost EOL, you should start thinking about upgrading to a newer version.

Comment: I'm using 4GB VPS with 3 cores for database and 8GB VPS for Odoo server (different VPS hosts). is there any tool tips to improve speed in this scenario.

Comment: You have to find the root cause and then you can fix it. Just being remote doesn't mean that a server is slow. All my database servers are remote and none of them is having performance issues, not even with 1000 concurrent users.

Comment: Start with `show all;`